# How is it a downgrade if I want to upgrade my app to 2.3.7+1 from 2.3.6+2?

Tags: android, flutter

I have my app installed on the device with version `2.3.6+2`.

I created the new version of it: `2.3.7+1`.

And it says I can downgrade the app if I want instead upgrade...?

What could be the problem?

Comment: "It says I can downgrade..." What is "it"?

Comment: Android itself at firebase site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you increase the `versionCode` as well as that `versionName` you showed?

See https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning

> The versionName has no purpose other than to be displayed to users.

Comment: Until now I increased the version like: `1.0.0+1 -> 1.0.1+1 -> 1.1.0+1 -> etc`, so I just changed the versionName. It should been like `1.0.0+1 -> 1.0.1+2 -> 1.1.0+3` etc? So basically increase that number every time there is a new release?

Comment: Reading that article it just seems you can fill in whatever you want in that string-based version (although I don't really understand your versioning scheme and I'd stick to semantic versioning if I were you). What is your versionCode (integer value) between those versions?